# Parsing text file, same field has either 1 or 2 names

Tags: c++, linked-list, text-parsing

I have a text file of NFL teams. I am having a problem when parsing through the string when it comes to teams with 2 names and not one. (i.e. New England and Pittsburgh) the next item in the file is an int. I also have to read these values into a linked list.

```
infile     >> t.date // t is a team struct which contains char name and ints
           >> t.name 
           >> t.W
           >> t.L
           >> t.T
```

Can I just use an if else statement between the name and Wins to check if the next char is a char? And then if it is a char it could just save the next word, "England" for the second half of New England's name in the same name field, and if its an int it will move on to the Wins field.

txt file ex

> New England   2   4   0
>   Pittsburgh    1   6   0

the code above was what I was trying to use to assign the name to the team struct

```
   struct team
{
public:
    team& do_input(std::istream& is);

    std::string date, name, name2;
    int wins, 
        losses, 
        ties;
    std::string perc,
        home, 
        road,
        div,
        conf;
     int league;
};
   infile >>t.date;

   while (infile >> t)
    {
        t.do_input(infile) ;
        //cout << t.date << t.name;
        L.push_back(t);
        t.name2 = " ";
}
```

Comment: Post some code and the format in which the data is stored in the text file.

Comment: I then use L.push_back(t) to add to the list

Comment: File template please.

Comment: the text file? an example of what it looks like is above. New England 2 4 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's start by maintaining your code. The first thing I would do is create an overload of `operator >>` that takes an input stream and a `team` object.

```
std::istream& operator >>(std::istream& is, team& t);
```

This function should delegate the operation of extracting the input to a method called `do_input()`:

```
std::istream& operator >>(std::istream& is, team& t)
{
    if (is.good())
        t.do_input(is);
    return is;
}
```

`do_input` should read objects of type `char` into the respective string objects in your `team` class. Speaking of your `team` class, it's much better to use [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) for representation of string values:

```
struct team
{
    ...
    std::string date;
    std::string name;

    int W, L, T;
};
```

This way the string can be as large enough as we need it. We no longer have to worry about a potential buffer overflow (i.e reading a string larger than 10 bytes). We can also use the convenient methods that `std::string` provides.

It's further recommended that you use good variable names so that maintainers of your code can know at a glance what it means. For instance, try these:

```
int wins, losses, ties;
```

Now it is clear to me (and to others) what these names imply.

---

So `team::do_input` is a member function that reads in the strings and integers from the file to the data members of the instance from which it is being called. Here's a full implementation:

```
struct team
{
public:
    team& do_input(std::istream&);
private:
    std::string date, name;
    int wins, losses, ties;
};

team& team::do_input(std::istream& is)
{
    std::getline((is >> date).ignore(), name);
    is >> wins >> losses >> ties;

    return *this;
}
```

Error reporting has been left out to keep the example concise. I hope this helped.

Comment: I get what you're trying to do. Where you used "data" I use date, as in the date in the file. it has one date then 32 teams with the above mentioned format. Does this mean I shouldn't use that while loop that i was trying before... When it returns those vars, namely name, wins, losses, ties, it will create a team object for every team? I'm still lost.

Comment: Sorry, I made a typo with the name; it *should* be `date`. Moreover, when implementing, you would do something like `team t; while (infile >> t) ...;`, not like your original loop. I have a question: Is `date` supposed to be the name of the team? Or is `name` both the first and last name of the team?

Comment: name would hold both the first and last name of the team. Or, only one if its not a two-part name, like pittsburgh, or carolina, vs New England or NY Jets

Comment: @user2989625 So then what is `date` supposed to be?

Comment: 10/18/2013
New England  3 2 0 .600 1-1-0 2-1-0 1-0-0 3-1-0 1

NY Jets  2 3 0 .400 1-2-0 1-1-0 2-0-0 2-2-0 1

Buffalo  2 3 0 .400 1-1-0 1-2-0 0-2-0 2-2-0 1

Date is on its own line, and then every team is on its own line also

date \n 
New England wins losses ties win% homerecord roadrecord divrecord confrecord and division (an int 1-8 to represent the division)

Comment: @user2989625 Is there only one date in the text file?

Comment: changed the while condition and fixed it, 0x499602D2 you were very helpful. If i could upvote I would, however I do not have enough rep yet. I really appreciate it.

Comment: @user2989625 I'm glad I could help. Can you accept my answer (click the checkmark)?  It helps a lot! :D